# Expert advisor in different trader platform

Tags: metatrader4

I would like to know, if I code an EA in a normal metatrader4 platform, can I reuse the .ex4 in other trading platform for example InstaTrader?

The reason is that, when I have created a new EA in InstaTrader, the EA code generated from InstaTrader is different from the one generated from metatrader4. And I couldn't find any documentation regarding to InstaTrader's EA.

Not sure anyone has encountered this before?

Comment: InstaTrader has any extra functions ? Probably not so yes, you can use EA on any MetaTrader4 in any broker.

Answer (score 0):

No. MQL is the language specifically for meta-editor which is a member of meta-trader platform.
Other trading languages may have their own scripting languages.

Comment: No is **not a correct answer** in the asked context. **EX4** cannot be executed on non-Metatrader4 platform.

Answer (score 0):

## Metatrader4

In principle Metatrader4 uses a `Metalang.exe` that compiles the **`MQL4`**-`source-code` files into an "internally"-executable format **`EX4`**

As defined, **`EX4`** is binary-executable on all Metatrader4 terminals.

.

## WhiteLabel-ed Terminals

InstaTrader(TM) and many other *-Trader(TM)-s are so called White-Label modifications of the same MetaQuotes, Inc., software product, the [**`Metatrader 4 Terminal`**], that are just individually "skinned" in a name of the respective Broker, who has bought from the MetaQuotes, Inc. the license for a suite of [**`Metatrader 4 Server`** + **`Metatrader 4 Risk Management`** + **`Metatrader 4 Dealer Desk`** + ... ], inclusive, but not limited to, the right to re-label the client Terminal program.

Thus under most of the situations your **`EX4`** code shall run on any other re-labeled Terminal

## But...

Restrictions on binary-compatibility apply, as Metatrader4 terminals gets released in so called Builds, ( Build 432 -> Build 468 -> Build 509 -> ... -> Build 600 -> Build 624 ) and some of these have also modified the binary-code format.

Thus the **`EX4`** code shall be hosted on a "similar" generation of the Terminal Build

## Finally...

The ultimate show-stopper is the MetaQuotes, Inc., licensing policy, which makes a server-side locking to take place [**`Metatrader 4 Server`**] has a setting to reject connection requests from client Terminals in case their `Build #` is lesser than a treshold set on Server side.

There the SLM story ends. Forever.